# Tasks in C#: Error Passing Double Type Functions as Parameter

Tags: c#, task

I am trying to perform a task in which the expected return is of type `double`. As a parameter, I pass the task a *function* of type `double` as well. Below is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace Tasks
{
    class Program
    {
        private static double Dobro(double x)
        {
            return 2 * x;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Task<double> dobro = new Task<double>(Dobro(15));


            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

However, I have had the following **compile time error** in return:

> CS1503  C# Argument 1: cannot convert from 'double' to 'System.Func'

How to solve this?

Comment: `new Task<double>(() => Dobro(15));`

Comment: You also should start your `Task` to get a result

Comment: looks a lot like homework...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to create `Task` from lambda function *itself*:

```
   Task<double> dobro = new Task<double>(() => Dobro(15));
```

Or (create and *run* lambda function based task)

```
   Task<double> dobro = Task<double>.Run(() => Dobro(15));
```

In case you want to wrap lambda function *execution result* (i.e. execute `Dobro(15)` and return the result as *completed* `Task`)

```
   Task<double> dobro = Task<double>.FromResult(Dobro(15));
```